# How do I take all inputs from a dash page and store them in a database/dataframe?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I have a dash script which has the users filling in inputs and dropdowns; first with inputs then filling in a dropdown datatable. I need to take these inputs and datatable once they are filled in, and after clicking the ‘Submit’ button, will be stored as a pandas dataframe or dictionary or stored in the database (whichever is easiest, to be frank).

I feel like I may need to use dcc.Store and callbacks of course, but I’m uncertain on how to proceed.
Any help appreciated, thank you!

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([
    ('Product', ['Benzene', 'HDPE', 'Propylene', 'Benzene']),
    ('Function', ['Input1', 'Input2', 'Input3', 'Input2']),
    ('Conversion Factor', [1, 2, 1, 3]),
    ('Measure Unit', ['Tonne', 'Kilo', 'Tonne', 'Gram']),
]))


app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children='Technology Information',
                style={'font-family': 'calibri'}),
        dcc.Store(id='memory'),
        dbc.FormGroup([
            dbc.Label('Technology Name:',
                      html_for='tech-name-row',
                      style={'font-family': 'calibri',
                             'margin-right': '4em'}),
            dbc.Col(dbc.Input(type='technology',
                              id='tech-name-row',
                              placeholder='Enter Technology Name',
                              style={'display': 'inline-flex',
                                     'verticalAlign': 'middle',
                                     'height': '25px'}),
                    style={'display': 'inline-flex',
                           'verticalAlign': 'middle'}),
        ], row=True, style={'margin-bottom': '1em'}),
        html.Label(["Technology Type:", dcc.Dropdown(id="tech-type-drop",
                                                     style={'display': 'inline-block',
                                                            'width': '175px',
                                                            'height': '28px',
                                                            'margin-left': '2.3em',
                                                            'verticalAlign': 'middle',
                                                            'font-size': '15px'},
                                                     placeholder='Select Type',
                                                     options=[
                                                        {"label": "Type 1", "value": "1"},
                                                        {"label": "Type 2", "value": "2"},
                                                        {"label": "Type 3", "value": "3"}])],
                   style={'font-family': 'calibri',
                          'margin-right': '4em',
                          'display': 'flex'}),
        html.H1('                                   '),
        html.H1('                                   '),
        html.H2('Process Information',
                style={'font-family': 'calibri',
                       'margin-right': '0.5em',
                       'margin-top': '3em',
                       'display': 'inline'}),
        html.Button(children='+',
                    id='add_process_button',
                    style={'background-color': '#38BC23',
                           'display': 'inline'}),
        html.Div(id='process_list', children=[]),
        html.Div(id='process_output', children='No output'),
        html.Button(children='Submit',
                    id='submit-form',
                    type='submit',
                    style={'background-color': '#0099ff',
                           'margin': '1em'}),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output('process_list', 'children'),
    [Input('add_process_button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input({'type': 'remove_process_button', 'index': ALL}, 'n_clicks')
     ],
    [State('process_list', 'children')])
def add_step(n_clicks, _, div_list):

    input_id = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    if "index" in input_id and n_clicks is not None:
        delete_form = json.loads(input_id)["index"]
        div_list = [form for form in div_list if "'index': " + str(delete_form) not in str(form)]
    else:
        div_list += [html.Div(children=[
            dcc.Store(id='memory'),
            html.Button(children='-',
                        id={'type': 'remove_process_button', 'index': n_clicks},
                        style={'background-color': 'red',
                               'display': 'inline',
                               'float': 'right',
                               'margin': '1em'}),
            dbc.Col(
                dbc.FormGroup(
                    [dbc.Label("Process Name",
                               html_for="process-name",
                               style={'font-family': 'calibri',
                                      'margin-right': '2em'}),
                     dbc.Input(id="process-name",
                               placeholder="Enter Process Name")],
                    style={'margin': '1em'})),
            html.Div(children=[
                dash_table.DataTable(id='process-table',
                                     data=[{}],
                                     style_table={'margin': '2em', 'width': '90%', 'display': 'inline-block'},
                                     style_cell={'font-family': 'calibri', 'textAlign': 'left'},
                                     columns=[{'id': 'Product', 'name': 'Product', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
                                              {'id': 'Function', 'name': 'Function', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
                                              {'id': 'Conversion Factor', 'name': 'Conversion Factor',
                                               'presentation': 'dropdown'},
                                              {'id': 'Measure Unit', 'name': 'Measure Unit',
                                               'presentation': 'dropdown'}],
                                     row_deletable=True,
                                     editable=True,
                                     dropdown={'Product': {'options': [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in
                                                                       ['Benzene', 'HDPE', 'Propylene']]},
                                               'Function': {'options': [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in
                                                                        ['Input1', 'Input2', 'Input3']]},
                                               'Conversion Factor': {'options': [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in
                                                                                 ['1', '2', '3']]},
                                               'Measure Unit': {'options': [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in
                                                                            ['Tonne', 'Kilo', 'Gram']]},
                                               }),
                html.Button('Add Row',
                            style={'background-color': '#38BC23', 'display': 'inline', 'margin': '1em'},
                            id='editing-rows-button',
                            n_clicks=0),
                html.Div(id='process-table-container')
            ])
        ], style={'border': '2px black solid',
                  'margin': '1em'}
        )]
    return div_list


@app.callback(
    Output('process-table', 'data'),
    [Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('process-table', 'data'),
     State('process-table', 'columns')])
def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({c['id']: '' for c in columns})
    return rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything will be triggered by the submit button, then you can set up a callback to use the submit button as `Input`, and everything else as `State` to the function. Then that function can package the data however you need and send it off to your database, file system, or whatever.

Comment: That sounds logical and correct, but when I try to use a dbc.Input in state e.g. 'tech-name-row' in this case, I am given an error:
This ID is assigned to a dash_bootstrap_components.Input component
in the layout, which does not support this property.
I also tried to use pattern matching callbacks and giving all required points id={'type': name, 'index': index} but since I already use the datatable in a callback its proving difficult.

Comment: Its a property in another callback. The code works even with this error so I've chosen to ignore it until I find a more permanent solution. However your original advice was really helpful and allowed me to get to this point, so thank you!